# how to get the value from a CSS class object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to select an `<a>` element from the given class of objects. when i click on the anchor tag in the `showcase_URL` class, i want the jquery function to get the value from `<a>` tag. 
How can this be done?

I cannot make this an `id` as I am running a while loop to construct all the elements in php. there would be multiple objects of this class. there is no definite selector through which I can get the value of the anchor tag. Help would be much appreciated.

```
        echo '<div id="content">';  
        echo '<div class="showcase_data">';
        echo    '<div class="showcase_HEAD">'.$row->title.'</div>';
        echo    '<div class="showcase_TYPE">'.$row->type.'</div>';
        echo    '<div class="showcase_date">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row->date.'</div>';
        echo    '<div class="showcase_THUMB" style="float: left;" ></div>';
        echo    '<div class="showcase_TEXT">'.$row->details.'</div><br/>';
        echo    '<div class="showcase_URL"><a class="purl" value='.$row->num.'href="'.$row->url.'">PROJECT URL</a></div>';
        echo    '</div>';
        echo    '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `attr()` function like this:

```
$(".showcase_URL a").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

Note:  You should have quotes and a space here like this:

```
value='.$row->num.'href="'.$row->url.'"
```

to:

```
value="'.$row->num.'" href="'.$row->url.'"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.showcase_URL a').click(function(e) {
  alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){
   var value = $(this).attr("value");
});
```

This will monitor the value element on all anchor tags clicked. You can filter that by class, or only those anchor tags beneath the showcase_URL div. Your question really doesn't specify what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.showcase_URL a.purl').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('value'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get text or any other data bind on click event to your anchor:

```
$('a.purl').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).html();
});
```